# Mapping Data Returning Same Value - Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I'm mapping over some data (3 image slides i have stored in a headless cms). I am passing the retuned data into slide component, and from there its being passed down to a button component, which is just a 'gatsby-link'. The mapped data contains a "page_link", among other things that should be different for each slide. However, for some reason the same "page_link" is being passed down to each button, even though they should all be different. I am logging my data in the console and can confirm that each array i am mapping over contains different data. I get the different image, title, text, etc fields for each slide, but i am recieving the same "page_link" for each slide. I am confused as to what i am doing wrong.

Heres my code:

GraphQl Query:

```
const HOMEPAGE_DATA = graphql`
  query {
    prismicHomePage {
      data {
        body {
        slider {
          title {
            text
          }
          text {
            text
          }
          page_link{
           text
          }
          button_text{
           text
          }
          image {
            localFile {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1280, quality: 90) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

  // get homepage data
  const data = useStaticQuery(HOMEPAGE_DATA)

  // simplify data
  const home_data = data.prismicHomePage.data
```

Mapped Data:

```
        {home_data.slider.map((slide, index) => {
          console.log(slide)
          return (
            <Slide
              key={slide.title.text}
              title={slide.title.text}
              image={slide.image.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
              text={slide.text.text}
              button_text={slide.button_text.text}
              path_link={slide.page_link.text}
            />
          )
        })}
```

Slide Component:

```
const Slide = props => {
  return (
    <StyledBackgroundImage fluid={props.image} alt={`${props.title}`}>
      <Wrapper>
        <SlideContent>
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <p>{props.text}</p>

          <div className="slide-btn">
            <Button path={props.path_link} text={props.button_text} />
          </div>
        </SlideContent>
      </Wrapper>
    </StyledBackgroundImage>
  )
}
```

Button Component:
The  is just a Styled "Link" Component from Gatsby.

```
const Button = props => {
  return (
    <StyledButton to={props.path} title={`${props.text}`}>
      {props.text}
    </StyledButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: You refer to `path_url` in your question but I don't see it in your code.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: path_url is a value coming from a graphql query i have, image, title, text are also included in this query and are working displaying as they should

Comment: Will you please show where you use it in your code?

Comment: my mistake @larz, i had meant "page_link" in my question and not "path_url", i've updated my question so it is less confusing

Comment: i have also included my graphql quesy @larz

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!  To my eyes, it looks like it should be passing correctly, especially if you see it when you `console.log(slide)`.  Maybe try adding a `console.log(props)` inside your `Button` component?

Comment: @larz, i will try this for sure tonight! i'm just so confused as to why they are all receiving the same page_link, if replace the button text with {props.path}, each button text will display the different paths, however when the prop is being passed to the actual link prop ( to={...} ) each link returns the same "/products/california-shutters" link